# JTAppleCalendar scrollToDate not working on far away dates

Tags: ios, xcode, jtapplecalendar

So, I am using JTAppleCalendar and I have been running into this issue.

In my application I have a calendar view with a reset button that should scroll back to selected date, it works just fine whenever I reset from less than 4 months ahead, but if I go further and try to reset nothing happens, I tried using scrollToDate(date:) , and reloadData(withAnchor:)

nothing happens, I added break-points inside of those functions in the pod, and it does hit the function, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your issue got fixed or not.
scrollToDate(date:) works perfectly and only time it wont work is, when your end date used to configure calendar is earlier than the date that you are trying to scroll to.